# How do you update your "HOMEBREW_TEMP" environmental variable?

Tags: homebrew

I'm getting the following error when running "brew doctor":

```
Error: Your Cellar and TEMP directories are on different volumes.
OS X won't move relative symlinks across volumes unless the target file already
exists. Brews known to be affected by this are Git and Narwhal.

You should set the "HOMEBREW_TEMP" environmental variable to a suitable
directory on the same volume as your Cellar
```

How do I set this variable? And what should I set it to? I can't seem to find anything about this when googling.

Comment: What is the output of `brew --cellar`? Is the volume that resides on different then the one `/tmp` is on?

Comment: [~] $ brew --cellar
/usr/local/Cellar

Comment: It's not a different volume, it's just a standard macbook pro. I don't use any other harddrives.

Comment: Hmm, odd. If you haven't recently, run `brew update` to make sure everything is up-to-date, and see if that helps. If not, you'll probably have better luck [posting on issue with Homebrew directly](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues) (just don't forget to post the solution back here!).

Comment: thanks, I did try brew update and that didn't help. I'll file an issue and report back.

Comment: Ok, so a restart to my computer fixed that. Weird.

Comment: Odd. You should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

For anyone that runs into this in the future, try restarting your computer and then running `brew doctor` again. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You set your `HOMEBREW_TEMP` by editing your `~/.bash_profile` and doing this:

`export HOMEBREW_TEMP=/new/path`

Then start a new shell.

Alternatively type that into any already open shell.

Google *setting shell environment variables* for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by setting the path of the temp folder manualy.
First i created a folder `temp` in `/usr/local/` 
and then added the following to my zsh file `nano ~/.zshrc`

```
export HOMEBREW_TEMP=/usr/local/temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred to me. I actually have configured separate disk in memory for /private/tmp. Hope that's why this error occurred.

To solve this issue, create a directory somewhere, like /usr/local/brew_temp

Then add following line to file ~/.profile. If file doesn't exist create that file

```
export HOMEBREW_TEMP=/usr/local/brew_temp
```

In each restart it will set the HOMEBREW_TEMP environment variable to that path. After setting these option either you can restart OS X or run following in command line if you don't want to restart

```
. ~/.profile
```